# Enabling wlan on Raspberry Pi 3 bare linux

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, buildroot

I have built the linux system for my RPi3 using buildroot. It boots properly and I can access the wired connection properly. However, I am stuck with enabling the wlan.

Here is what I have done so far.
Built the filesystem using buildroot:

```
make raspberrypi3_defconfig
make
```

After booting linux successfully I followed [this](https://delog.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/wireless-on-raspberry-pi-with-buildroot/) link to enable wlan.
As the author of the post mentions, I had to select some of the wireless related packages by running `make linux-menuconfig`. But when I did run it, these packages were already selected. 
I then ran `make menuconfig` and selected wpa_supplicant and other packages.

Now, when I boot the RPi3, wlan0 is not listed when I run `ifconfig -a`. I googled it a bit and found that there should be folder named `wlan0` under `/sys/class/net/`. But I can only find `eth0` and `lo`

Kindly guide me on how to get the wlan working. dmesg log is posted [here](http://pastebin.com/W72GaUg2)

Comment: Already covered [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45745/pi3-built-in-wifi-and-buildroot).

Comment: Which OS you are using ? I am using Ubuntu Mate and everything is working fine.

Comment: @MickSharpe I already tried the solution. It didn't work for me

Comment: @SakibSami Yes. it works for me too if I flash raspbian. I am trying this on my custom linux.

Comment: @MickSharpe In fact I don't have a /lib/firmware/brcm/ . What might be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Buildroot, make sure you have selected BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_WIFI_FIRMWARE.

Also you have to manual load the wifi kernel module:

# modprobe brcmfmac

After that, you can confirm wlan0 with

# ifconfig -a

You could also configure Buildroot to build udev as /dev management option, in this case, WiFi kernel module will be loaded automatically.